# Store constant variable without using database

Tags: cakephp

I have a situation. I want to calculate the point depended on 2 pre-defined variables, let's say they are $limit and $point

For example:
   $limit = 100 => $point = 2

if I have k $limit, and the formula to calculate the $averagepoint is 
   (k$limit * $point) / $limit

The question is. I want to set $limit and $point dynamically. It means I want to allow the user to set the amount of $limit and $point.

However, I do not want to store the values which are given by the user for $limit and $point in database.

Where and How I suppose to store and do?

Any suggestion is valuable.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

i may be missing something but when a user sets the data points why not set a cookie?

Comment: cookie is good, but the cookie expires when the browser is closed. I want to store $limit and $point unchanged when set.  any other suggestion i_forget?

Comment: you can set an expiration date on a cookie to last til the user deletes it

Comment: Howeber, other user cannot get the see the value in cookie.

Comment: that is true and i thought was irrelevant in the way i read the question. Then maybe you can write to a xml file. If I may ask, why not use a db if you want everyone to see everyone elses options?

Comment: here the situation. the user who can set $limit and $point is the Admin of the website.

Comment: you can either generate a ini or xml file when the admin switches the vars or make a xml/ini file that the admin edits directly

Comment: outstanding idea. Can you show me the way? I am new to cakephp

Comment: ini: you would just make a windows style ini file and then use built in php function parse_ini_file to read in the contents. XML: just make a standard xml and you can read in with simpleXml

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't want to store it in the DB. But based on your requirement, the easiest way is using Configure class:

> ```
>   // save data
>    Configure::store('<type>','<filename>', $data);
>   // read data back
>   Configure::load('<filename>');
>   $data= Configure::read('<type>');
> ```

type can be anything really, but the recommended options are 'Models', 'Controllers', 'Helpers', 'Components'

Interesting enough, the store function is not documented in the Cookbook (you can find it in the API)